# How to paginate with mongoose with query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, mongoose, pagination

Im new in backend and node js.
**what I want to achieve:**
i have calendar dates, and i want to query data for the day that clicked.

1. right now i have function that get all the meetings from all the days:

   ```
    //GET ALL MEETINGS//
   exports.getMeetings = async (req, res) => {
    const meetings = await Meeting.find()
   .populate("determinedBy", "_id name")
   .sort({ date: -1 })
   .select("_id massageType startDate endDate")
   .then(meetings => {
       res.json({ meetings });
   })
   .catch(err => console.log("get meetings", err));
   ```

   };
2. i want to change this method to get only all the meetings that the user clicked (if user click date 21/9/2020 so get all the meetings from this date and so on...
   my schema is like so:

   ```
   const meetingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   massageType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["נשימות", "תאילני", "שוודי", "רקמות עמוק"],
   required: "Massage type is required",
   },
   startDate: {
   type: Date,
   required: "date is required",
   },
   endDate: {
   type: Date,
   required: "date is required",
   },
   determinedBy: {
   type: ObjectId,
   ref: "User",
    },
    created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    },
   });
   ```
3. Im using **axios** from the frontend to get the meetings to the state.

   ```
     ////////GET ALL MEETINGS////////
     const getAllMeetings = dispatch => async () => {
     dispatch({ type: "loading", payload: true });
    console.log("ss");
     try {
      const response = await indexApi.get(`/meetings`);

      dispatch({
       type: "get_meetings",
       payload: response.data.meetings,
      });
      dispatch({ type: "loading", payload: false });
      } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
       type: "add_message",
       payload: `something went wrong with sig `,
        });
       dispatch({ type: "loading", payload: false });
       }
      };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const cutoff = new Date(); // The date you need.
const pageOptions = {
    page: parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 0,
    limit: parseInt(req.query.limit, 10) || 10
}

MeetingModel.find({startDate: {$lt: cutoff}})
    .skip(pageOptions.page * pageOptions.limit)
    .limit(pageOptions.limit)
    .exec(function (err, doc) {
        if(err) { res.status(500).json(err); return; };
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    });
```

I'm from Israel too :) Glad to help.

Comment: in the axios i need to do simple get? or need to declare something to do the paginate? right now my axios get look like:
  const response = await indexApi.get(`/Meetings`);

Comment: It depend on your query. Add the axios code to your original question.